# How to add additional columns to existing gridview programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in a user control. I am using `BoundField` for displaying columns in gridview in aspx page. Can I add additional columns from code behind file (.cs)? I need to add few additional columns in the user control is used in different page.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a new `cell in RowDataBound` event of the gridview, like below. (I have added the comments where needed)

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
   {
     TableHeaderCell NewCell = new TableHeaderCell();
     NewCell.Text = "Header Text";
     e.Row.Cells.AddAt(4(Index of Cell where you want to add cell), NewCell);
   }


if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
       TableCell NewCell= new TableCell(); 
       NewCell.ID = "NewCell";
       NewCell.Text = "Text value of cell which you want to display";
       e.Row.Cells.AddAt(4, NewCell);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

create a method to add columns in user control, and keep it accessor public.
Now call that function from the aspx page where you have you that control object.